# how to get value at an address with radare

Tags: radare2

If I'm using radare2, and I run, lets say `dr` while debugging, it'll print pointers for some of the registers.
Lets pretend like `esp` is resolving to `0x04084308` or something similar.
If I want to get the value that `esp` is pointing to, how could I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

print `rsp` register value

```
[0x560207c7275a]> dr?rsp
0x7fffa5e429c8
```

print 4 bytes hex at 0x7fffa5e429c8

```
[0x560207c7275a]> px 4 @rsp
- offset -       0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x7fffa5e429c8  9b00 dae7                                ....
```

print 8 bytes hex at 0x7fffa5e429c8 ( command `px` == `x` )

```
[0x560207c7275a]> x 8 @rsp
- offset -       0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x7fffa5e429c8  9b00 dae7 347f 0000                      ....4...
[0x560207c7275a]>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with drr, which will show more information about the registers, such as where they point :).

Otherwise, if you want to get a value in the programs memory, you can s 0xaddr and then V to show information near there.